# How do you pass additional data from a razor page to a partial view and the back-end in .net core?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, razor, .net-core-3.1

I have been relying on this web tutorial: [Ajax Partial Page Updates in Razor](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/ajax/partial-update)

In this tutorial I have done something to match this partial view:

```
@page
@model RazorPagesTests.Pages.AjaxPartialModel
<h2>Ajax</h2>
<p><button class="btn btn-primary" id="load">Load</button></p>
<div id="grid"></div>
@section scripts{
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#load').on('click', function () {
                $('#grid').load('/ajaxpartial?handler=CarPartial');
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

The main Razor page has this included and works fine:

```
@page
@model RazorPagesTests.Pages.AjaxPartialModel
<h2>Ajax</h2>
<p><button class="btn btn-primary" id="load">Load</button></p>
<div id="grid"></div>
@section scripts{
    <script>
        document.getElementById('load').addEventListener('click', () => {
            fetch('/ajaxpartial?handler=CarPartial')
                .then((response) => {
                    return response.text();
                })
                .then((result) => {
                    document.getElementById('grid').innerHTML = result;
                });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Then in the main .cs page of the app, I do something like this:

```
public PartialViewResult OnGetCarPartial()
{
    Cars = _carService.GetAll();
    return Partial("_CarPartial", Cars);
}
```

However, I see that the examples above pass a model to the partial view and the Ajax Fetch API passes only a handler in the URL to the base page.

**Questions**

1. How do I pass an int and string values to the base page based on user data?
2. Can you add ajax/Fetch API calls in the base razor app that apply to things that have been updated in the UI of the partial view?

Comment: why do you need to update the base razor page? as partial views are meant to manage part of the entire page.

Comment: Do you mean you want to pass an int value to Partialview,ans want to use ajax/Fetch API to call  partial view?

Comment: I want to pass in two strings

Comment: How do I pass two strings from the base page into a model and then send it back to the partial view for processing?